# How to add condition to changeSet

Tags: liquibase

I created database ChangeLog for liquibase and I have "CREATE TABLE" query.
I want to add condition to column "STATUS".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">


    <changeSet id="1" author="xxx">
        <comment>Create Asset table</comment>
        <sql>
            CREATE TABLE `TASK`(
            `TASK_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
            `STATUS` VARCHAR(10), //(where status not equal to "pending")
            `FILE_ID` varchar(100),
            PRIMARY KEY (`DOC_ID`)
            )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: What do you expect if `status` equals `pending`?

Comment: to get failure.

Comment: I don't get it. You are trying to create a **new** table. It means, that there is no data in `status` column. How could status be equal to something at the moment of table creation?

Comment: It sounds as if you are looking for a check constraint - MySQL does not support that, so you are out of luck.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using a `<sql>` tag to create a table, not a `<createTable>` tag?

Comment: Actually I have to update the table with this condition, do you have any other suggestion how can I do so?

Comment: There is some important reason to call the tag  <createTable>  instead of <sql> ?

Comment: What exactly do you need to update in the table? Change the datatype?

Comment: yes. I have to change the datatype

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update the columns datatype depending on certain conditions, you can use `<preConditions>` with `<sqlCheck>`, and then use `<modifyDataType>`.

So supposing that there's already a table with name `TASK` and it contains a column named `STATUS`, you can modify it's datatype as such:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="xxx">
    <comment>Update Asset table</comment>
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <and>
            <columnExists tableName="TASK" columnName="STATUS"/>
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="0"> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TASK WHERE STATUS = "pending";</sqlCheck>
        </and>
    </preConditions>
    <modifyDataType tableName="TASK" columnName="STATUS" newDataType="VARCHAR(10)"/>
</changeSet>
```

Or perhaps you'd like another `onFail`-behaviour. Check out this [link](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html)

> **HALT** - Immediately halt execution of entire change log [default]
>
> **CONTINUE** - Skip over change set. Execution of change set will be
>   attempted again on the next update. Continue with change log.
>
> **MARK_RAN** - Skip over change set, but mark it as ran. Continue with
>   change log
>
> **WARN** - Output warning and continue executing change set as normal.