# Condition in creating view - liquibase xml

Tags: sql, xml, view, liquibase

I want to make some view but with condition in my fourth column.

CONDITION:
If epr.j_id is not null then fill lj.id  BUT WHEN  epr.j_id is null then fill 'NONE'

I've found some condition tag there but I have no idea how I can use it or maybe there is some another way...

```
    <changeSet id="103" author="m">
    <createView replaceIfExists="true"
                schemaName="public"
                viewName="report">
        SELECT DISTINCT l.id,
        l.name,
        l.gis_ext_id AS gis_ext_id_line,
        condition (epr.j_id is not null ),
```

Answer (score 0):

From a previous StackOverflow question: [How to add condition to changeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000846/how-to-add-condition-to-changeset)

> If you want to update the columns datatype depending on certain conditions, you can use `<preConditions>` with `<sqlCheck>,` and then use `<modifyDataType>.`
>
> So supposing that there's already a table with name TASK and it contains a column named STATUS, you can modify it's datatype as such:
>
> ```
> <changeSet id="1" author="xxx">
>     <comment>Update Asset table</comment>
>     <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
>         <and>
>             <columnExists tableName="TASK" columnName="STATUS"/>
>             <sqlCheck expectedResult="0"> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TASK WHERE STATUS = "pending";</sqlCheck>
>         </and>
>     </preConditions>
>     <modifyDataType tableName="TASK" columnName="STATUS" newDataType="VARCHAR(10)"/>
> </changeSet>
> ```
>
> Or perhaps you'd like another onFail-behaviour. Check out this [link](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html)
>
> - HALT - Immediately halt execution of entire change log [default]
> - CONTINUE - Skip over change set. Execution of change set will be attempted again on the next update. Continue with change log.
> - MARK_RAN - Skip over change set, but mark it as ran. Continue with change log
> - WARN - Output warning and continue executing change set as normal.

Additional Documentation:

- Liquibase: [Create View](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-view.html)
- Mohit Goyal: [Check database state and conditionally apply changes in the Liquibase](https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/03/26/check-database-state-and-conditionally-apply-changes-in-the-liquibase/)